# Logstash not writing to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am having an error where Logstash is not writing a parse document to elasticsearch when the message property contains hierarchical message data.  When the message property does not contain hierarchical data it works fine.   Here is some data that works:

```
{
  "Layer": "Web",
  "DurationMilliseconds": 65,
  "CreatedOn": "2014-09-29T20:44:40.5380157Z",
  "Enviroment": "Dev",
  "AssemblyName": "LoggingTest",
  "ClassName": "HomeController",
  "MethodName": "Index",
  "WindowsIdentity": "XXX\\YYY",
  "SessionId": "wrm11rken3lc442humrxyhoe",
  "Application": "LoggingTest",
  "Machine": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
  "Browser": "Chrome",
  "@version": "1",
  "@timestamp": "2014-09-29T20:45:38.432Z",
  "type": "Perf"
}
```

Here is some data the does not work:

```
{
  "Enviroment": "Dev",
  "Level": "Fatal",
  "CreatedOn": "2014-09-29 20:46:30.5042",
  "WindowsIdentity": "XXX\\XXX",
  "Application": "LoggingTest",
  "UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36",
  "SessionId": "wrm11rken3lc442humrxyhoe",
  "URL": "/LoggingTest/jsnlog.logger",
  "UserAddress": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
  "Message": {
    "stack": "TypeError: undefined is not a function\n    at Log (http://XXX/LoggingTest/:58:16)\n    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (http://XXX/LoggingTest/:66:141)",
    "message": "undefined is not a function",
    "name": "TypeError",
    "logData": "JS Fatal Exception"
  },
  "@version": "1",
  "@timestamp": "2014-09-29T20:46:30.331Z",
  "type": "JS"
}
```

Here is my logstash config:

```
input {
    redis {
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        type => "JS"
        data_type => "list"
        key => "JS"
    }
}

filter
{
    json{ source => "message"}
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug}

    elasticsearch { 
        host => localhost 
        index => dev
    }
}
```

When I run the above code through the first item is parsed into my elasticsearch successfully but the 2nd one disappears with no errors written by logstash.

Answer (score 0):

I have change with your logs. Here is my config,

```
input {
    stdin{}
}

filter{
    json{ source => "message"}
}

output {
    stdout {
            codec => "rubydebug"
    }
    elasticsearch {
            host => localhost
            cluster => "BENLIM"
    }
}
```

With this config, when I send the logs which do not work to logstash, it can parse and output to the elasticsearch. FYI.

Comment: I can tell from the stdout that the message is being retrieved from the Redis queue and parsed as valid JSON.  I tried adding the cluster name to the elasticsearch output but it did not fix the problem.  The first one is still added to elasticsearch and the 2nd one is not.

Comment: I was able to make this work by parsing out the child message into seperate fields instead of keeping them nested